# problem with running java code in cmd windows

Tags: java

I want to run `DepthFirstSearch.java` from the following website:
https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/DepthFirstSearch.java

I put it in a folder new with the `algs4.jar` from the above website. I use the following to compile in WINDOWS:
`javac -cp algs4.jar DepthFirstSearch.java` which compiles correctly. However, when I run 
`java -cp algs4.jar DepthFirstSearch`
I get the error that main class could not found or load.
Does anyone know how I can solve this?
Best Regards,

Comment: `java -cp algs4.jar edu.princeton.cs.algs4.DepthFirstSearch` - The package is part of the class name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you I tried. It worked.

Comment: @rph my question was specifically for java codes from the mentioned website. However, the link that you sent can cover it.